# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Problem With Release Statement

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access

I don't know what is wrong with that statement because I have exactly the same code which I copied from another project of mine but it just keeps throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS when everything looks fine. Can anybody pinpoint the problem? Much greatly appreciated as I have been on this error for hours, the same code keeps producing different results such as either bad access or I get a white screen.

Code Fragment:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

NSLog(@"0");
UINavigationController * localNavigationController;

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

//ProductViewController
ProductViewController * productViewController;
productViewController = [[ProductViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];

localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: productViewController];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
NSLog(@"1");
// memory statements
[localNavigationController release];
[productViewController release];


//Search View Controller
SearchViewController * searchViewController;
searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: searchViewController];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];

// memory statements
[localControllersArray release];
[searchViewController release];
NSLog(@"2");
//Register View Controller
RegisterViewController * registerViewController;
registerViewController = [[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];
localNavigationController  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:registerViewController];

[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
NSLog(@"3");
//memory management
[localControllersArray release];
[registerViewController release];

//About View Controller
AboutViewController * aboutViewController;
aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: aboutViewController];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];

//memory management
[localNavigationController release];
[aboutViewController release];
NSLog(@"4");
// Override point for customization after application launch.
tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;


[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

The NSLog was to see where was the problem. The 3 doesn't show up after [localNavigationController release].

I have attached the project.

http://www.mediafire.com/?eauye5s361cyej0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about code fragment instead?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to download and unzip a whole project and then guess where the error is.  Please post some code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the static analyzer**

Really, use "Analyze" from the product menu, and it will pin-point the problem within a second.

In

```
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
```

you use the array that you released some lines before.

Edit: And yes, posting code instead of upload a project is the way to go. Guess I just happen to have a nice day and downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

The error is with:

```
[localControllersArray release];
```

just after your `NSLog(@"3");` statement.

`localControllersArray` has already been released before the `NSLog(@"2")` statement.

The solution is to remove the `[localControllersArray release];` before the `NSLog(@"2")` statement.